# Why am I getting bad request from google?

Tags: c++, qt, google-drive-api, qt5

**My objective**
To exchange refresh token for access token from google using OAuth 2.

My code

```
bool Google_Account::Refresh_Access_Token_Using_Refresh_Token()
{  
    // Prepare Url
    QUrl url(tr("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"));

    // Create request
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setRawHeader("Host:","www.googleapis.com");
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Create request body ClientID, ClientSecret, RefreshTokenString are class data members
    QString RequestBody = tr("client_secret=%1&").arg(ClientSecret) +
                          tr("grant_type=refresh_token&")+
                        tr("refresh_token=%1&").arg(RefreshTokenString)+
                          tr("client_id=%1").arg(ClientID);

    QByteArray array = RequestBody.toUtf8();

    // Get reply
    QNetworkReply *reply = mQNAM.post(request, array); // mQNAM is QNetworkAccessManager

    // Set timeout to reply while waiting for reply finished
    bool stop = false;
    QTimer timer;
    timer.setSingleShot(true);

    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){
        qDebug()<<"Time out";
        stop = true;
    });
    timer.start(5000);

    // Wait till the response is completed
    while(!reply->isFinished()){
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        if(stop){
            qDebug()<<"Going to abort";
            reply->abort();
        }
    }

    // Check for reply
    if(reply->isFinished()){

        if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError){
            qDebug()<<reply->readAll();
            emit setMessage("Error: "+reply->errorString());
            delete reply;
            return false;
        }
        else{
            QByteArray array = reply->readAll();
            QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(array);
            QJsonObject obj = document.object();
            access_token = obj.value("access_token").toString(); //access_token is class data variable
            delete reply;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        delete reply;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I run this code in my windows 7 pc(Qt 5.11.1) everything is fine I get the access token but if i run in my raspberry pi(raspbian Qt 5.7) I get Error 400, Bad request from google. I tried using the access_token got from my windows pc and made other request such as to get the file list from google drive, they are working fine in raspberry, but only this I am having problem. What am I doing wrong?
P.S the code is refactored to the specific details only, in reality I am getting the client id and other keys from QSettings

Comment: I suggest you avoiding the QCoreApplication::processEvents() approach, since it just leads to problems. Rework your code with an asynchronous approach.

Comment: @Giancarlo Ok I will try that

Answer (score 0):

This smells like you're getting a 400 code when Qt is requesting a token, because the login code you get when the flow returns to your app is URL-encoded. We wrote about [How To Authenticate with Google SSO in Qt](https://appfluence.com/productivity/how-to-authenticate-qt-google-sso/) with some code samples including this bit that injects a parameter modifier in the flow:

```
google->setModifyParametersFunction([](QAbstractOAuth::Stage stage, QVariantMap* parameters) {
   // Percent-decode the "code" parameter so Google can match it
   if (stage == QAbstractOAuth::Stage::RequestingAccessToken) {
      QByteArray code = parameters->value("code").toByteArray();
      (*parameters)["code"] = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(code);
   }
});
```

Do that before the initial request, but as suggested by @Giancarlo above, I'd rewrite your code to work asynchronously. It's simpler, and more reliable.